# IPCOP DHCP not working on green interface with two wireless routers connected via switch

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipcop

**Hardware**

I have IPCOP setup (green + red) 
- Red connecting to the internet with no issues via a static IP provided by my ISP
- Green interface (192.168.0.1) using DHCP on the range of 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254 all with subnet 255.255.255.0
- 1 x Switch (8 port)
- 2 x TD-W8960N Version 7 (TP-LINK 300mb Adsl Routers) 
- One of the TD-W8960N routers (Router A) I have given the IP address 192.168.2.1 with DHCP and NAT off, for IPv4 and IPv6
- The other TD-W8960N router (Router B) I have given the IP address 192.168.2.2 with DHCP and NAT off, for IPv4 and IPv6

**Setup**

I have a switch connected on the green interface, and any device plugging into the switch via an ethernet cable works 100%. The DHCP from the IP cop correctly assigns the IP from the available pool between the 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.254 range, and can access the internet

**Goal**

I would like to attach both wireless routers to the switch, one for my pc room the other for the cottage on my property, and have the IPCOP DHCP handle the assignments.

**Problems**

If I plug either one of the routers A or B on the switch (NOT BOTH) the setup works with one router connected and any device connecting to the router correctly received an IP address from the DHCP. IF however I plug both router A and B onto the switch then any device connecting to either of the networks DO NOT receive a valid IP from anywhere I get the std self assigned ip 165......

**Testing Setups**

1 - IPCOP Green -> Switch -> Router A (works)

2 - IPCOP Green -> Switch -> Router B (works)

3 - IPCOP Green -> Switch to Both -> Router A (does not work) + Router B (does not work)

I have tried all permutations of lan to lan / wan to lan / lan to wan. Even tried daisy chaining the routers on to each other

**Where to from here**

If anyone could help me with a suggestion of where to go from here that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got a suggestion on the tomshardware forum http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3412665/ipcop-switch-wireless-routers.html to put router A and B on the network and test a wired connection which lead to the below findings:

Check there for the findings